# Public key encryption using PKCS

Tags: java, aes, public-key-encryption

I have looked into many threads to understand about how to create a PKCS encrypted file, but sadly none of the thread worked for me.

I am working on a requirement where I have to generate a PKCS file (p7 extension) using bounce castle(jdk 8) or any other API if available. If anyone has a working example of generating the PKCS encrypted file that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the question wasn't very clear, but I figured out the way to create a PKCS envelop using the bouncy castle API's. I am posting the answer here, it may be helpful to someone.

```
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSAlgorithm;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.bc.BcRSAKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.OutputEncryptor;

// Create the pkcs #7 envelop and add content to it
            CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator fact = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
            fact.addRecipientInfoGenerator(
                    new BcRSAKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(new JcaX509CertificateHolder((X509Certificate) cert)));
            OutputEncryptor encryptor = new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.DES_EDE3_CBC).setProvider("BC")
                    .build();
            CMSProcessableByteArray content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(zipdata);

            CMSEnvelopedData envdata = fact.generate(content, encryptor);
            byte[] enveloped = envdata.getEncoded();
```

'cert' is the X509 certificate, you can create a self signed certificate or a CA certificate. 'zipdata' is the byte array contents of the zip file and 'enveloped ' is the byte array PKCS envelop which contains the zip data.